# Convert 2d array into flat associative array with one column as keys and other columns imploded with space

Tags: php, arrays, dictionary, multidimensional-array

I have an array of type

```
$records = array(
array(
    'id' => 2135,
    'first_name' => 'John',
    'last_name' => 'Cena',
),
array(
    'id' => 5623,
    'first_name' => 'Peter',
    'last_name' => 'Doe',
));
```

I want to display the output in the format of

```
[2135] => John Cena
[5623] => Peter Doe
```

I have been using following code to try to display my expected result but its not working.

```
$names = array_column($records, 'first_name' . 'last_name', 'id');
```

How can I concatenate two columns of array into one?

Comment: Please check the manual for [array_column()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php). It doesn't take four arguments, it takes three. The first one being the array, the second the column (one column) to get and the third argument decide what column to use as index.

Comment: I went through it, that is why I'm trying to send four arguments as three.

Comment: Ah. Missed that you concatenated the strings for the second argument. That won't work. That's the same as writing `array_column($records, 'first_namelast_name', 'id);`. That will make it look for a column literally called `first_namelast_name`, which doesn't exist. You can't concatenate two columns with this function. Use the code in @shubham715 answer instead.

Comment: @shubham715 yes Im going through it right now

Comment: @MagnusEriksson okay will try his code

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create a new array by using foreach loop.

**Try this**

```
  $newArray = [];
    foreach($records as $key => $value) {
      $newArray[$value['id']]= $value['first_name']." ".$value['last_name'];          
    }

   print_r($newArray);
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [2135] => John Cena
    [5623] => Peter Doe
)
```

Comment: `$key` is never used, therefore there is no reason to declare it in your loop.

Answer (score 7):

The reason your current code is not working is because you are asking PHP to look in the `$records` array for the key `first_namelast_name`, which doesn't exist.

`array_column` only returns a single column, as stated in the [PHP manual entry](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php)

> (PHP 5 >= 5.5.0, PHP 7)
>
> array_column — Return the values from a single column in the input

You need to loop through the array and concatenate the strings manually. One function you can use is `array_reduce`:

```
$names = array_reduce($records, function ($result, $item) {
    $result[$item['id']] = $item['first_name'] . ' ' . $item['last_name'];
    return $result;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it by creating the another array. Simply merge the value of sub-array in new created array using **foreach** loop.

```
$records = array(
array(
    'id' => 2135,
    'first_name' => 'John',
    'last_name' => 'Cena',
),
array(
    'id' => 5623,
    'first_name' => 'Peter',
    'last_name' => 'Doe',
));

foreach($records as $data)
{
  $temp[$data['id']] = $data['first_name'].' '.$data['last_name'];
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($temp);



// Output

Array
(
    [2135] => John Cena
    [5623] => Peter Doe
)
```

Comment: A good answer includes an explanation of _why_ the OP should use it. What problem does it solve? How does it solve it?

Comment: Try this (code only) answers are low-value on StackOverflow because they do a poor job of educating/empowering the OP and thousands of future researchers. Always include some explanation with EVERY answer that you post. Don't wait 'til next time, please edit this answer.

Answer (score 1):

array_column works on that kind of problem but here it can't concatenate first_name and last_name keys so You can also try this code -

```
$records = array(
array(
    'id' => 2135,
    'first_name' => 'John',
    'last_name' => 'Cena',
),
array(
    'id' => 5623,
    'first_name' => 'Peter',
    'last_name' => 'Doe',
));

$tmp = [];

foreach($records as $key) {
    $tmp[$key["id"]] = $key["first_name"] . " " . $key["last_name"];
}

print_r($tmp); // Array ( [2135] => John Cena [5623] => Peter Doe );
```

Comment: Try this (code only) answers are low-value on StackOverflow because they do a poor job of educating/empowering the OP and thousands of future researchers. Always include some explanation with EVERY answer that you post. Don't wait 'til next time, please edit this answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is no php builtin function to do that i guess. You may loop through array and concatenate them.

```
$records = array(
array(
'id' => 2135,
'first_name' => 'John',
'last_name' => 'Cena',
),
array(
'id' => 5623,
'first_name' => 'Peter',
'last_name' => 'Doe', 
));

$newArray = array();
foreach($records as $data)
{
$index = "";
$value = "";
$indexLoop = 1;
foreach($data as $reckey => $recValue)
{
    if($indexLoop ==1)
    {
        $index = $recValue; 
    }else{
            $value .= $recValue." ";
         }  

    $indexLoop++;
}

$newArray[$index] = $value;
}

 echo "<pre>"; print_r($newArray);
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you checked other solution before posting your answer? Your solution have poor logic as  well as no explanation.

Comment: When i was programming this code there was no other answer. I like the other solutions. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of filling out this page with more viable scripts, you can pull the first value from each row, use it as the new key, then implode the remaining column values.  The advantage of this is that you don't have to manually express the keys to access the data.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/aCIee))

```
$result = [];
foreach ($records as $row) {
    $result[array_shift($row)] = implode(' ', $row);
}
var_export($result);
```

Or

```
var_export(
    array_reduce(
        $records,
        fn($result, $row) => $result + [array_shift($row) => implode(' ', $row)],
        []
    )
);
```